# How to add video Casting for the chewie player in flutter?

Tags: flutter, video, casting

I make flutter video player player with chewie package.but I want add casting option for it how I add those changes?

Answer (score 0):

i fount this package , but u should drop chewie_player i think :

[flutter_video_cast](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_video_cast) and [flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player)